# Naming collisions in AngularJS definitions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently trying to organise my Angular application in such a way that it will scale appropriately to an enterprise level. However I'm finding that there seems to be an over-reliance on naming conventions within the framework, and trying to avoid naming collisions is a real issue.

For example, when defining any `constants` / `controllers` / `directives` / `factories` / `filters` / `providers` / `services`, a name is supplied to be implicitly used during dependency injection.

This works great with a just a few definitions. However when there could be hundreds (maybe thousands) of these definitions, trying to manage and prevent duplicates seems to be a bit of a maintenance nightmare!

Another issue is the naming of directives. As there doesn't seem to be a way to apply any context to directives, it is not possible to have something like the following (i.e. reuse the name "button"):

```
<toolbar>
  <button></button>
</toolbar>

<customform>
  <button></button>
</customform>
```

Therefore we are again reliant on verbose naming conventions. If you include the recommended vendor prefix, you end up with something like this:

```
<company:toolbar>
  <company:toolbar-button></company:toolbar-button>
</company:toolbar>

<company:customform>
  <company:customform-button></company:customform-button>
</company:customform>
```

Which I admit isn't horrific, but it highlights how the reliance on naming conventions can easily cause collisions.

**Is there anything on the Angular roadmap to address the problem of namespacing, and what would be the current (1.0.6) recommended solution to the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution for this right now. It's definitely an issue as your apps get larger, or when you have to include arbitrary modules that may not be known at dev-time. I would recommend filing an issue for this with the [angular project](https://github.com/angular/angular.js).